# react-native-version-number:verifyReleaseResources in React Native application

Tags: reactjs, android-gradle-plugin, apk, version, react-native

I am doing react native application. And I tried to create apk file for android.

I have installed multiple components (libraries), In that to get version number, I have installed `react-native-version-number`.

But, While trying to create apk file, Getting following error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-version-number:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

How to fix this, Any suggestion.

Comment: Came here with the same problem. Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: It is sdk version, Please check your sdk OS version supporting and that library OS version.

Comment: For the ones who got this error, go to https://github.com/APSL/react-native-version-number/issues/41#issuecomment-484224505.
There is a solution.